# How to use Python AWS AppSync Client?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, graphene-python

I am currently looking for a python lib that could allow me to use my AWS AppSync API from my backend.

I looked at Graphene, but I didn't see support for AWS auth.

I also look at appsync-client, but the documentation is non-existent and the maintenance of the project seems to me absent.

If you have experience or the same concerns, your comments are welcome in order to find a solution together :)

Comment: Haven't had luck with the features for appsync before as well, but I have it somewhat working (without the subscriptions). It all depends on how you authenticate your AppSync, I have mine setup to use both Cognito and an API Token. I mainly use the API token to send mutation requests to the Appsync endpoint. It is a workaround at best I think.

Answer (score 1):

AppSync API has two endpoints.

**HTTPS endpoint such as `<id>.appsync-api.<region>.amazonaws.com` :**
For Query and Mutation, you can use a generic HTTP client to do POST with the GraphQL query as the body. If it's AWS IAM auth, you can refer to this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html). If it's API key auth, you need to add `x-api-key: <key>` to the headers. If it's Cognito auth, you need to add `Authorization: <jwt>` to the headers.

**WSS endpoint such as `<id>.appsync-realtime-api.<region>.amazonaws.com` :** For subscription, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-websockets-python/) for python client implementation.

Please let me know if you have any question.